# What difference does the __c make in currentPageReference in code?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, pagereference, lightningnavigation

What is the difference between keyword and c__keyword in the code below? What is happening below?

```
 this.searchKeyword = this.currentPageReference.state.keyword
      ? this.currentPageReference.state.**keyword**
      : this.currentPageReference.state.**c__keyword** ? this.currentPageReference.state.c__keyword : '';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously, you could just use `keyword`, but in order to tighten security, it was changed so that you would need to include the "namespace" as part of the state. For unmanaged code, this is always `c`, so the property becomes `c__keyword`. If this code were in a managed package, it would use the package's name (e.g. `pkgname__keyword`) when passing in the state to from outside the package.